# Bash script between report lines - Line Breaking

Tags: listings, line-breaking, code-snippets

I'm using the following commands to introduce bash script text in the middle of a report:

```
\newcommand{\shellcmd}[1]{\\\indent\indent\texttt{\footnotesize\# #1}\\}

\begin{document}
  \noindent Consider the following command:
  \shellcmd{apt-get --purge remove rubygems}
  This removes the \texttt{rubygems} package.
\end{document}
```

The problem is that when the line is too long, it breaks on the right corner of the page. How do I redefine it, so that the line breaks in line with the remaining text?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. `\texttt` does not break> Use listings or `tcolorbox`

Comment: Please never (never ever) do stuff like `\\\indent\indent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `tcolorbox` (tcblisting) way:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcommand{\shellcmd}[1]{\\\indent\indent\texttt{\footnotesize\# #1}\\}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  \noindent Consider the following command:
\begin{tcblisting}{arc=0pt,auto outer arc,listing options={language={bash}},listing only,every listing line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries username \$>}}}
  apt-get --purge remove rubygems
  apt-get --purge remove rubygems ;   apt-get --purge remove rubygems ;   apt-get --purge remove rubygems
\end{tcblisting}
  This removes the \texttt{rubygems} package.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ramaro: You're welcome. See the `tcolorbox` manual for more options